# Crop image with sharp using original size and stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, sharp

I'm developing an app in which user uploads avatar to the server and then he is asked to crop the image. All I need is to get an image size from stream and then crop it by percentage.

This is my current code but it's not working so far:

```
router.use('/', (req, res) => {
  //Crop parameters, these will be providen by user directly
  const parameters = {
    left: 0.5, //crop from left percentage
    top: 0.2, //crop from top percentage
    size: 0.5 //size percentage (extracted from width)
  }
  const fileStream = s3.getObject({
    Bucket: '<my-bucket-name>',
    Key: fileKey
  }).createReadStream();

  let imageInfo;

  const infoTransformer = sharp().on('info', info => {
    imageInfo = info;
  })

  const cropTransformer = sharp().extract({
    left: parameters.left * imageInfo.width,
    top: parameters.top * imageInfo.height,
    width: parameters.size * imageInfo.width,
    height: parameters.size * imageInfo.width
  });

  return fileStream.pipe(infoTransformer).pipe(cropTransformer).pipe(res);
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting **Image dimension** from the Image picker library and the size is coming from multer.

```
  _imageCompressor = (_image, dimension) => {
        const { width, height } = dimension
        const modifiedImage = sharp(_image)
            .resize(Math.trunc(width), Math.trunc(height))
            .toBuffer()
        return modifiedImage
    }
```

I am using this to compress my image without crop it.
dimension is the **width** and **height** in which I want to compress the image.
**_image** is image buffer which I want to compress
using this function I am getting compress image